# mysql : How can i protect to make field value negative

Tags: mysql, sql

i am creating a table. and i am using some update queries on it.

this table has `placeId, noOfGirls, noOfBoys.` due to some update queries the values of these two fields `noOfGirls and noOfBoys` becomes `negative.`

Is there a way so i can convert these `negative` values to `0`. means any constrains or something else so i can protect to be value negative.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sending these values from code behind or directly in sql?

Comment: Which version of MySQL? At least since 5.0.2 you should be able to use constraints to prevent the update or triggers to modify the update to change the negative values to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the column as `unsigned int` type.

The unsigned range is 0 to 4294967295, so the value never become negative.

You can alter the schema of your existing table

`alter table table_name modify column noOfGirls int(10) unsigned;`

You can read it more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to use an unsigned integer type:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(bar INTEGER UNSIGNED)
```

[The MySQL "numeric types" documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html) has more information on what this means.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it unsigned zerofill works, negative values will be converted to 0. you will get the following warning though
Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'a1' at row 1

other ways: you may create a trigger

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html